# Route::post() shows this error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

`Route::post()` shows the following error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219
```

I changed the route `::post()` into `get()`. That's working fine, but I want to use it this way:

`Route::post()`

Here is my form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" accept="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index');
```

How can I solve this error, where is the problem?

Comment: You have not defined the `action` attribute to your form

Comment: You use annotations in controller ?

Comment: Have you try `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you handle showing the form and its submitting in the same Controller method?

If so, you should have in the Routes both Methods allowed:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index');
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index');
```

Comment: have one method .this is my route i use in Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index'); if i can use Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index'); then working fine both have same  method chnage depend on error  but get method working fine post method show error

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any action attribute in your form. Try adding action="/posts" in form attributes.

Comment: i give it this <form role="form" method="post" accept="{{url('/posts')}}">   then same situation

Comment: i give it this the same situation <form role="form" method="post" action="{{url('/posts')}}">