# Without AJAX call simple post method is not working in Laravel, I'm not using AJAX simple form

Tags: php, laravel

`route ::post()`is not working fine on the other hand `route::get()` is working fine and other method is working, just post method is not working

```
     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

this route is working:

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesignation@index');
```

but this route is not working

use same form:

```
<form action="/form/process" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
</form>
```

how to resolve it

Comment: You have missed name attribute for <input> tag.

Comment: If you're using ajax then update your question with javascript code

Comment: @ghulam-abbas you should accept answers to your questions when they're correct you have 13 questions on SO with **NO** correct answer!

Comment: Did you ask the same question 3 hours earlier? Possible duplicate of [Route::post() shows this error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251739/routepost-shows-this-error-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you notice that the route in the form is `/form/process` it should be `/posts`